# Equalizing bunch of data Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I'm not sure what's is the correct way to describ my problem but I'll  try.

I've used different gains to record the sound of a machine because I used different Piezos to do it, my aim was to not overload the soundcard of my Pc, my question is there a way to "equalize" those records so when  I'll evaluate the PSDs  my analyse stay correct. or  I shouldn't care about this ?

Comment: I think you're more likely to get a good answer to this question over at http://dsp.stackexchange.com.  Arguably your question is off-topic here, it's not really a programming question.

Comment: I already tried it no answer :(

Comment: Cross-posting is rather frowned upon in the SE multiverse.  Perhaps you should ask an improved version of the question rather than repeating it all over the place.

Comment: NO Cross-posting  I've deleted the old on

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you're looking for a way to 'normalize' your data instead of 'equalize'.

There are multiple sorts of 'normalizations' that one can do on time series data.

Say, rawN is your raw Nth piezo's recording and procN is the processed and normalized data.

- Peak Normalization - Modify all data such that the peak value is the same.

  `procN = rawN./(max(abs(rawN(:)))); % Peak value of procN is 1 or -1`
- RMS Normalization - Here, you use some measure of overall 'loudness' to normalize two signals.

  `procN = rawN./sqrt(mean(procN.^2)); % Normalize to an overall RMS value of 1`

You can also get fancy and do a more 'equalization' approach, where you'd look into different frequency bands and try to match at that level, or have do short-term RMS normalization to match power/loudness over smaller chunks of the signals. But all this depends on your application.

Comment: I think that's what I need, the thing is that I have 20+ files that already are between -1 and 1 how can I normlize them to evaluate them correctly

Comment: It's hard to saw what you mean by "evaluate them correctly" with the limited information provided in the question.